# Why canvas text quality is low after requestAnimationFrame usage?

Tags: html, canvas, text, html5-canvas

I draw the text on canvas and then apply `requestAnimationFrame` to change its color:

```
var text = 'Sample text';
ctx.fillText(text,canvas_width/2,100);
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  ctx.fillText(text,-offset,100);
}
```

See [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/4775cp0t/) with full code used.

Initially text looks OK (jf you comment `requestAnimationFrame()` line):
[image: text before animation applied - looks well]
but after animation used it looks like below -
[image: text after animation]
You may notice white pixels there, which looks awful (please ignore the colors used - they are applied to demonstrate the problem).

What could be wrong there? 
I was thinking that it is probably caused by my offset/position calculations - `textWidth/2`, `cw/2`, but could it return different result from time to time?

I've tested the code with Google Chrome 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) under OSX 10.10.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not clearing the canvas, so the old text will stay there. That is the problem that is giving you your white pixels. This problem is (presumably) because of anti-aliasing.

To fix this problem, like I have mentioned, you're not clearing the canvas on every frame. Make sure you add this before you draw anything on the canvas:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But is it good approach from the performance perspective? And, still I would like to understand why without canvas clearing it doesn't work well...

Comment: Clearing the canvas really shouldn't cause much of a performance overhead, in fact, it could actually speed up the drawing of the canvas. The requestAnimationFrame function calls a function when the CPU/GPU is next available to process drawing to the canvas, afaik.